# what does "fulfill" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand this sentence:

> In Turkmen society, the song of men and women fulfilled important but quite different functions.

I don't understand what "fulfilled important" means. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Maryam, have you checked the meaning of "fulfill" in a dictionary?

Comment: yes, I checked it but what does it mean "fulfilled important"? How can I translate it into Persian?

Comment: to fulfill a function is to play a role. I have no idea  how you can translate it into Persian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Turkmen society, the song of men and women fulfilled important but quite different functions.

First of all, it's Turkmen, not Tukmen.

Second of all, to fulfill a function can also be expressed as: to play a role.

played important but different roles.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it's now more obvious where your problem is.

> In Tukmen society, the song of men and women *fulfilled* important but quite different *functions*.

It's not "fulfilled important", but "fulfilled functions".

"functions" is called the **head** of the phrase. "important" and "different" are its **dependents**, and "quite" is "different"'s dependent. The "but" somehow **connects** the two adjectives.

Let's consider another example:

> I have eaten candies.

If you add "some", to change it to

> I have eaten some candies.

it does not mean you have eaten "some"!

Comment: what is the synonym of "fulfill" here? realize?

Comment: @Maryam [yes, one of the meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fulfill)